# ¿Cómo enviar datos y cargar contenido de una página a otra con AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

espero y me puedan ayudar con mi problema, en este momento tengo dos archivos un "ingresar.php" (Log in) y otro "index.php" que hace parte del dashboard(admin), cada vez que ingreso al sistema se me crea un log en la base de datos dónde se registran los movimientos de los usuarios ¿Qué pasa? en el index del administrador tengo un DIV dónde me muestra los LOGS(de la base de datos)... *Anexo la vista DIV del administrador:https://prnt.sc/vn2x94* Y la idea es que cuándo cada cliente INGRESE, REGISTRE u otro movimiento este cargue "AUTOMATICAMENTE" y se actualice sin tener que volver a cargar la página(F5)... Exactamente ese DIV... Cabe resaltar que cada vez que creo un LOG lo hago desde el mismo "ingresar.php"(Login) *Anexo vista del "ingresar.php"(Log In): https://prnt.sc/vn30eu* ¿Hay alguna forma de qué cuándo registre el log, el DIV del administrador cargue sin tener que refrescar la página?

En este momento en el index.php del dashboard tengo esto implementado:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(
      function(){
        $('#contenidoLogs').load('./php/logs.php');
      }
      );
  });
</script>
```

Pero esta parte de código lo que hace es refrescar SIEMPRE esa parte del DIV y no quiero eso... quiero que lo haga cada vez que se registre un LOG... no tengo muchos conocimientos en AJAX, perdón mi ignorancia :(

Comment: Lo que quieres no es posible con ajax sin más, a no ser que hagas "pooling", es decir, estar constantemente enviando peticiones al servidor para ver si ha habido algún cambio en la tabla, ya que el servidor no tiene manera de conectarse con el cliente, las peticiones ajax SIEMPRE son de *cliente* a *servidor* y no al revés. Por otro lado, si eso no te parece tan mala idea te recomiendo que leas sobre la [**api fetch**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) que te permite hacer peticiones asíncronas de manera sencilla y sin necesidad de librerías externas

Comment: Muchas gracias @Benito-B miraré sobre el tema y si puedo hacerlo, estaré respondiendo por este medio :)

Comment: Si tienes cualquier problema aquí estamos. Feliz aprendizaje!

Comment: Es fácil. Aunque ya te dijeron que no. 1. prepara una página php que devuelva el estatus de entrada de usuarios al administrador. Ella actulizará en respuesta a llamados ajax la info que ve el administrador. 2. Activas un timer en la página del admin que invoca el método que llama al ajax. En su evento done atualiza y antes de salir recarga el timer. No te sugerí setinterval() en lugar del timer por cuestión de gusto. Yo prefiero setTimer y recargarlo luego de .done

Comment: **nota:** con el mecanismo que te indico la notificación **no es directa**. Simplemente, la página del admin consulta a intervalos casi regulares, los cambios de registro de ingreso de usuarios

Answer (score 0):

Intenta así ejecutando el ajax dentro de una función la cual vas a invocar primero así lo primero que hará es recargar en tiempo real:

```
mifunc();
codigo
codigo
function mifunc(){
$.ajax({

});
}
```

Ve a este enlace:
https://youtu.be/GeCNShiLdpc